# threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm recieving an error of threadid=1... I don't always get it but I do at a point in the app at sometime. Not sure what my specific error is. I've check line 164 and I don't see anything that would cause the result. Maybe something I need to add into my manifest? Here is my LogCat.

```
05-08 17:19:28.796: W/dalvikvm(8683): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e37438)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at com.example.speech.MainActivity$SpeechListener.onResults(MainActivity.java:164)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$InternalListener$1.handleMessage(SpeechRecognizer.java:442)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Main Activity Code:
    package com.example.speech;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  OnClickListener {

private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent; 
boolean reseter = false;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;
private volatile boolean mNoSpeechCountDownOn;
MediaPlayer testSound;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    boolean available = SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this);
    Log.d("Speech", "available = " + available);
    testSound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.soundclip);
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechListener());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 0);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
    Log.d("speech", "Mute on");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        Log.d("speech", "repeat");
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
        Log.d("speech", "Mute on");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }


}

private CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000)
{   
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        mNoSpeechCountDownOn = false;
        mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private class SpeechListener implements RecognitionListener {


    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        if (mNoSpeechCountDownOn)
        {
            mNoSpeechCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        Log.d("Speech", "onBeginningOfSpeech");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onBufferReceived");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d("Speech", "onEndOfSpeech");


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {

        if (mNoSpeechCountDownOn)
        {
            mNoSpeechCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        Log.d("Speech", "onError");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.d("Speech", "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            mNoSpeechCountDownOn = true;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.start();
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
        }
        Log.d("Speech", "onReadyForSpeech");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            Log.d("speech", "repeat");
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
            Log.d("speech", "Mute on");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }}
    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.d("Speech", "results");



        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (String match : matches) { if (match.equals("one"))  testSound.start();
                else if (match.equals("two")) testSound.start();
        }
        // Do whatever you want here
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            Log.d("speech", "repeat");
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
            Log.d("speech", "Mute on");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        //Log.d("Speech", "onRmsChanged");
    }

}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //must keep the onClick

}
}
```

Comment: Post MainActivity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
if(matches!=null) {
    for (String match : matches)
    /* ... */
}
```

matches may be null if there are no matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 17:19:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(8683):     at com.example.speech.MainActivity$SpeechListener.onResults(MainActivity.java:164)
```

Guessing that line 164 is

```
else if (match.equals("two")) testSound.start();
```

I suspect your `match` can be `null` sometimes. If so, the `match.equals...` code will crash for pretty much obvious reason. The simplest solution is to change this line, from:

```
else if (match.equals("two")) testSound.start();
```

to more safe form:

```
else if ("two".equals(match)) testSound.start();
```

Comment: Strange.... receiving the same error for some reason... although I must admit that was a clever almost solution.

Comment: Also, line 164 is for (String match : matches) { if (.... so on... I did change both the "two" and "one" to the way you suggested, so shouldn't be a problem now.